# How to load TensorFlow Keras model from a saved checkpoint in Colaboratory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I've built and trained an RNN model in Colaboratory, and saved it using the checkpoint callback:

```
tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint( filepath=chkpt_p, save_weights_only=False)
```

And the saved data looks like this:

[image]

If I understand correctly, this directory includes both the model and the weights. Which function should I use to restore it (in another runtime)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(save_dir,compile=False)
```

I had one issue with using `tf.saved_model.load`, which doesn't produce a keras object, and one TF not finding the loss function with `compile=True`.